# After using axios in my portfolio app, it is not working and i'm receiving this "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."

Tags: javascript

This is my axios version:

```
 "dependencies": {
"axios": "^0.27.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"uuid": "^8.3.2"
```

}

This my main.py:

```
from colorama import Cursor
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
import pymysql

app=Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
@app.route("/api/Recommendation",methods=["GET"])
def data1():
db=pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",   
password="password",db="portfolio",autocommit=True)
Cursor=db.cursor()
query1="Select * from recommendation Where onshowcase=True"
Cursor.execute(query1)
recommnedation_data=Cursor.fetchall()
results_data=[]
for recommendations in recommnedation_data:
    recommedation_obj={
        "id": recommendations[0],
        "cardtitle": recommendations[1],
        "cardbody": recommendations[2],
        "cardfooter":recommendations[3]
    }
    results_data.append(recommedation_obj)
Cursor.close()
db.close()
return {"issuccessful":True,"results":results_data}
```

Here I'm using axios after applying this code my site is not working, if I remove this it starts working again.

```
async componentDidMount()
    {
        const response= await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:9001/api/Recommendation");
        this.setState({
            recommendation: response.data.results_data,
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are there any errors on the browser's development console?

Comment: "The above error occurred in the <Context.Consumer> component:" Yeah i found this error but in my code I see nothing wrong before that

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `chrome` browser then follow this steps:

1. Open Chrome on your computer.
2. Click. Settings.
3. Click Security and Privacy.
4. Click Site settings.
5. Click JavaScript.
6. Select Sites can use Javascript.

Make sure it's `enable`

If still not resolved then refer this [link](https://www.upbeatcode.com/react/solved-you-need-to-enable-javascript-to-run-this-app/)

There are multiple reasons why you see You need to enable Javascript to run this app error.

Comment: it is already enabled in my browser, thanks tho :)